# How to define Enumeration Constants in XSD?

Tags: xsd

I was looking to add system defined constants through an XSD. Here is a complex type that I have defined.

```
<xs:complexType name="app_job">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="cron" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I am looking for adding system defined constants like

```
DAILY (1, "0 0 0 * * ?", "Daily Job")
HOURLY (2, "0 0 0/1 * * ?", "Hourly Job")
```

I was trying enumeration here

```
<xs:simpleType name="app_jobs">
    <xs:restriction base="app_job">
        <xs:enumeration id="1" cron="0 0 0 * * ?" description="Daily Job"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But that does not seem right. Is there any way instance of the complex type with predefined values can be defined in same schema so that xsd2java can convert it to Java enum and I can use it in application? Instead of hand writing the enum, I wanted to source it from XSD.

Thanks in advance

Comment: seems that your question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168532/xsd-definition-for-enumerated-value)

Comment: I saw those before posting the question. Those are enumeration of string type. This one is enumeration of complex type.

Comment: missed that, sorry

Comment: Enumerations are only supported on simple types as far as I know. An assert (XML Schema 1.1) would allow restricting the value space to simulate an enumeration on a complex type, however it would probably not be converted to a java enum.

Comment: hmm. Is there any other way a constant complex type can be defined?