# Issue with LINQ inside XML Literals when generating XSD

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, xsd, xml-literals

I'm creating an enumeration inside an XSD according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1168850/832052). This is what I am aiming for, for reference:

```xml
<xs:simpleType name="color" final="restriction" >
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="green" />
    <xs:enumeration value="red" />
    <xs:enumeration value="blue" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="SomeElement">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Color" type="color" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The enumeration comes from an `IEnumerable(Of String)` from which I thought to directly generate a series of these elements `<xs:enumeration value="value1" />`

Whenever I run my code, it creates xml correctly up to the point where LINQ is used, where it starts escaping > and < as  `&gt;` and `&lt;`.

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="Instruments">
  <xs:simpleType name="InstrumentName" final="restriction">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">&lt;xs:enumeration value="AccuvimDL"/&gt;&lt;xs:enumeration value="AccuvimDLSignal"/&gt;&lt;xs:enumeration value="AlignmentFormBase" ...
```

My code:

```vb
Private Sub saveXsd(names As IEnumerable(Of String), typeName As String, typeType As String)
    Dim xsd = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <xs:schema id="Instruments" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                  <xs:simpleType name=<%= typeType %> final="restriction">
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <%= From name In names
                              Select $"<xs:enumeration value=""{name}""/>" %>
                      </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:element name="SomeElement">
                      <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                              <xs:element name=<%= typeName %> type=<%= typeType %>/>
                          </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
              </xs:schema>
    xsd.Save("xsd.xsd")
End Function
```

I also tried with this syntax for the LINQ part

```vb
<%= From name In names Select <xs:enumeration value=<%= name %>/> %>
```

but the `<xs:` namespace is not recognized because it is no longer part of the xml literal and can't compile.

I want to know if this should be possible. I think the xml literal feature of VB.Net is cool and I hope to be able to use it.

**Edit:**

Writing the question must have knocked something loose in my head. I found a solution, though not ideal.

The second LINQ method will work if I add a namespace

```vb
<%= From name In names 
    Select <xs:enumeration xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" value=<%= name %>/> %>
```

However I end up with the namespace in each element. I guess it's ok for an xsd...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="Instruments">
  <xs:simpleType name="InstrumentName" final="restriction">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" value="AccuvimDL" />
      <xs:enumeration xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" value="AccuvimDLSignal" />
      <xs:enumeration xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" value="AlignmentFormBase" />
      ...
```

Still open to other suggestions

Comment: Please mark the thread as answered, also tag it with the generator technology razor?

Comment: @sprotty it's not using razor. Still hoping for a solution without the namespace if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry wasn't familiar with the VB.Net XML literals, so I was intrigued.

Looks like you need the import

```vb
Imports <xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xsd = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                  <xs:schema id="Instruments" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <xs:simpleType name=<%= "test" %> final="restriction">
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                              <%= From name In names
                                  Select <xs:enumeration value=" {name}"/> %>
                          </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                  </xs:schema>
        xsd.Save("xsd.xsd")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know about the Imports xml namespace. Thanks